# MySQL: increment column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need update query where I can increment value by 1

Edit: Correct answer has been marked. I hope it will help some needy

Comment: "Can have int value", do you mean that it's sometimes an int and is stored as a char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <fieldname>=<fieldname>+<additional-value> WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 3):

a query to add a value to a column:

```
update table
set column=column + your_value
where some_conditions
```

This is what you want?